# Is there an "official"-ish complete chronological order for Star Wars C-canon material (books+comics+games)?

Tags: star-wars, chronological-order

I'm looking for a chronological order of ALL of Star Wars books, comics and games (a.k.a. C-canon).

Ideally, I'm looking for an "official" list which includes all the recent works (e.g. something that will keep getting updated in the future as new ones are released, with a high degree of likelyhood). It should include ALL of the known Star Wars books, not just the main novels (including the entire timeline, from the origins of the Sith in 130,000 BBY to post-New-Jedi-Order books), all of the comics and all the games.

So far I was unable to find an actual **complete** chronological list - the two best results I got was:

- A [list of works on Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_books) - it has a chronological list of novels (which seems to be a bit incomplete to me at first glance) but doesn't have comics/games included in the chronology even though it has a separate list of comics.
- ["Chronology of Star Wars" article on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_Star_Wars). While it's a great reference for general ttimeline, AND includes wonderful chronology of games (best I saw so far), the list of novels seems WAY too small of a subset (10 BBY to 40+ ABY only and I think some books are missing even from that period).

Is there a list that's better (more complete and actively maintained) somehwre I missed? Ideally something from Lucas Empire itself, or some other reputable SW-related source.

P.S. I'm fine if there are separate lists for books, comics and games, as long as each of them satisfies the requirement of being complete and likely to be kept that way as new ones come out.

**NOTE:** The purpose of the list is so I can try and read 100% of SW material in "correct" order. So lists that only include "major" books are unfortunately of no use, as are full chronology of *events* that don't cite the sources those events are mentioned in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link below takes you to an almost complete list (it does not include games).

http://www.swbooks.co.uk/timeline/

Answer (score 8):

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Essential_Chronology

That might be what you're looking for, although I'm not sure how much they cite which book/show/movie/game/etc each documented event comes from.  There's also:

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Publishing_eras

Which seems like it fits your request better, and will probably be kept up to date.

Comment: (1) Chronology of *events* is of little use to my purpose (read ALL the C-canon in chronological order) as it doesn't help me to order the works. In addition, that article is based on a book last updated in 2005. (2) The publishing eras is unfortunately only listing "Major works" and is thus incomplete by design.

Comment: The other thing I noticed on Wookieepedia is that they have pages for years of events.  If someone were to trudge through all of those articles, they could build the chronology you're looking for.

Comment: @DVK, there are a lot of crazy fans out there.  I'm sure there are more than a couple who could type down the chronology you're after.  Let's hope one stumbles by.

Answer (score 2):

Wookieepedia's [Timeline of canon media](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_media) is a maintained list of media part of the new canon. Likewise, [Timeline of Legends media](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Legends_media) lists media canonical in the Legends continuity, though I'm not sure if it includes S-canon media or not.