# Is there a list of all Halo-related reading?

Tags: suggested-order, halo

As a fan of the Halo games and its lore I was thinking about getting all of the books or comics that are a part of the Halo lore.

**I was wondering if anyone had a full list of all the books related to Halo's lore.**

Also if the list can be put in chronological order that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question seems totally on-topic to me; it's no different to any other suggested-order question.

Comment: **1/2** @N_Soong Suggested-order inherently asks about **all** works as well. In this case, the user doesn't know the initial list of works. This is merely an composite of story-ident and suggested-order.

Comment: **2/2** See: [What should I do if I want to cover 100% of Star Wars EU but don't want to play the games?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41192/21267) and [Is there an “official”-ish complete chronological order for Star Wars C-canon material (books+comics+games)?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2289/21267)

Comment: The lists of books and comics in the [Halo universe](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Halo_Franchise) seems short enough that this can be re-opened.

Answer (score 4):

Here's all the novels and comics in the *Halo* universe, in my (approximate) chronological order (some books skip a little around in the timeline):

- The Forerunner Saga, set during the Forerunner era:

  - *Halo: Cryptum*
  - *Halo: Primordium*
  - *Halo: Silentium*
- *Halo: Broken Circle*, about the formation of the Covenant
- Main series:

  - *Halo: Contact Harvest*, the beginning of the Human-Covenant war
  - *Halo: The Cole Protocol*, also the beginning of the Human-Covenant war
- *Halo Wars: Genesis* (comic), bridges *Contact Harvest* and the game *Halo Wars*
- *Halo: Blood Line* (comic), about a black ops team prior to the fall of Reach

  - *Halo: The Fall of Reach* (novel and comics adaptation), about the fall of Reach (which the game *Halo: Reach* is a loose adaptation of
  - *Halo: The Flood*, novelization of the game *Halo: Combat Evolved*
- *Halo Graphic Novel* (comic), different stories set around and after the events of *Halo: Combat Evolved*

  - *Halo: First Strike*, set between *Halo: Combat Evolved* and *Halo 2*
- *Halo: Helljumper* (comic), set at some point prior to *Halo 2*/*Halo 3: ODST* (actually not sure when)
- *Halo: Uprising* (comic), set between *Halo 2* and *Halo 3*

  - *Halo: Ghosts of Onyx*, jumps around a bit in time
- *Halo: New Blood*, sequel to *Halo 3: ODST*
- *Halo: Last Light*, set after *Halo 3* in 2553
- *Halo: Shadow of Intent*, set after *Halo 3* in 2553
- *Halo: Hunters in the Dark*, also set after *Halo 3* in 2555
- Kilo-Five Trilogy, sequels to *Ghosts of Onyx*, set after *Halo 3* starting around 2553:

  - *Halo: Glasslands*
  - *Halo: The Thursday War*
  - *Halo: Mortal Dictata*
- *Halo: Initiation* (comic), set before *Halo 4*
- *Halo: Escalation* (comic), also set before *Halo 4*

In addition there's a collection of short stories from different points in the chronology:

- *Halo: Evolutions - Essential Tales of the Halo Universe*